# Find all real x such that $\cos x$, $\cos2x$, $\cos 4x$, $\cos 8x$, etc. ($\cos 2^n$ for all non negative $n$) are all negative

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I think I got that $|\cos (2^nx)|$ must be less than $|\sin (2^nx)|$ for all non negative $n$.

Comment: Thinking about this in terms of angles in the plane, with the right leg along the positive $x$-axis, you need all angles that are in the second or third quadrant, such that if you double the angle repeatedly, you stay in the second or third quadrant indefinitely. It should be easier to see the answer like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_n = \cos 2^n x$. Then $c_{n+1} = 2c_n^2-1$. The function $c \mapsto 2c^2-1$ has two fixed points, $c=1$ and $c=-\frac12$ (these are just the roots of the quadratic equaton $2c^2-c-1=0$).

We are only interested in the negative solution $c = -\frac12$. The derivative of $2c^2-1$ at $c=-\frac12$ is $-2$, which is greater than $1$ in absolute value; so this fixed point is unstable, and the iterations of any point not exactly equal to $-\frac12$ will diverge.

Hence the only solution is $c=-\frac12$, and therefore $x$ is any number such that $\cos x = -\frac12$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to solve this without calculus, just using trigonometric formulas? I just don't know any calculus.

Comment: But cos (2*5pi/8)= sin (2*5pi/8). Maybe theres a little flaw in your solution?

Comment: @JackiePoehler: Do you mean $\cos (2^5\pi/8)$? That's not negative!

Comment: no, I mean that cos (5pi/8)=-1/2 but cos of the doubled angle is equal to the sin of the doubled angle.

Comment: @JackiePoehler: $\cos (5\pi/8) \ne -\frac12$. And anyway, what does sin have to do with anything?

Comment: Oh yeah my bad sorry. So is there a simple way to prove that only those angles x such that cos x=-1/2 suit? Thanks in advance. I have school in 2hrs and i'm trying to get ready for the most important assignment this fall.

Comment: One question: what do you mean by fixed points?

Comment: @JackiePoehler: You don't need calculus, you can do it with algebra. But it's a bit messy. You have to show that if $c_1 < 0$ and $c_1 \ne -\frac12$, then there exists $M > 1$ such that $|c_{n+1} + \frac12| \ge M|c_n + \frac12|$. Thus $|c_n + \frac12| \ge M^{n-1}|c_1+\frac12|$ increases without bound.

Comment: A fixed point of $x$ of a function $f$ satisfies $f(x)=x$.